# LSTM implementation in CNTK

Tags: machine-learning, lstm, cntk

I'm working on CNTK, and want to implement LSTM for classification task, and wish to design a network similar to the image on link:

> **Network**: https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-2cb991f854d93cf9380532d4945ca70b-p
>   **Input**     :    47*5 
>   **Output**  :    1

In network the first 47 length features of input goes into LSTM cell at x(t-1), then next 47 length feature goes in the cell in next step and this continues till 5 step.

I wrote this function:

```
def para_model(para):
    with default_options(init = glorot_uniform()):
        return Dense(attr_hidden_dim, activation= C.sigmoid)(Sequential([
            Recurrence(LSTM(para_hidden_dim))(para[:47]),
            Recurrence(LSTM(para_hidden_dim))(para[47:94]),
            Recurrence(LSTM(para_hidden_dim))(para[94:141]),
            Recurrence(LSTM(para_hidden_dim))(para[141:188]),
            Recurrence(LSTM(para_hidden_dim))(para[188:])
        ]))
```

I need to verify whether model is correct or not, also suggest correct model (with explanation)

Comment: What dimension does the Dense layer have, could you clarify? Does it project a single 235-dim vector, or individually 5 47-dim vectors with a shared transform?

Comment: It should project the last 47 features to the dense layer, which classifies into two classes.